# How to call a toast if api call is success or error?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I need help understanding and implementing toast messages in an Angular + Ionic 6 app...

In my app I want to show a toast message upon some events like clearing a cart, submitting an order, etc... In this case I want the toast message to display the message that is sent to me via an API call.

I have tried the ionic docs implementation but I'm not sure how to call the toast message and pass it the message.

In POSTMAN the message response looks like this:

```
{
    "message": "You have successfully cleared the cart"
}
```

**Here is the API call for clearing the cart (cart.service.ts):**

```
  clearCart() {
    return from(Preferences.get({key: 'TOKEN_KEY'})).pipe(
      switchMap(token => {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token.value}`);
        return this.httpClient.delete<ShoppingCart>(`${environment.apiUrl}cart`, {headers, observe: 'response'});
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        console.log(err.status);
        if (err.status === 400) {
          console.log(err.error.message);
        }
        if (err.status === 401) {
          this.authService.logout();
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/login', {replaceUrl: true});
        }
        return EMPTY;
      }),
    );
  }
```

**And here is the clearCart function with the presentToast function from the ionic docs in my cart page (cart.page.ts):**

```
          clearCart() {
    this.cartService.clearCart().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.products = [];
        this.totalProducts = 0;
        this.totalCartPrice = 0;
        this.successToast(data.body.message, 'bottom');
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
        this.errorToast(error, 'bottom');
    });
  }

        async successToast(message, position: 'bottom') {
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: message,
      duration: 1500,
      color: 'success',
      icon: 'checkmark-circle-outline',
      position
    });

    await toast.present();
  }

  async errorToast(message, position: 'bottom') {
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: message,
      duration: 1500,
      color: 'danger',
      icon: 'close-circle-outline',
      position
    });

    await toast.present();
  }
```

Have I even gone on a correct path on implementing the toast messages or have I f*cked up in the beginning of it? :)

Where do I call the presentToast function? How do I pass the message in it? do I need to make a new toast component?

Comment: Should be this.errorToast(error.message, 'bottom'). Other than that it looks as it should work.

Comment: @chuftica I have tried the error.message and the toast doesnt appear

Comment: Few things to try: try calling errorToast on success so you confirm that the method works. If that works, confirm are you really getting an error? Because the error code will only run when you get an invalid response from delete request(error codes 40X, 500, you can confirm that going to developer tools -> network and sending the request again, should be red with invalid response code). Last thing, since you're console logging error, you can see the object properties in console, maybe error.message is wrong.

Comment: @chuftica OK so Errortoast works on succes... On error 400 I see red colored call under network... I am console loging error and I see the response message in console log...

Comment: @chuftica What I have figured out is that the console.log error comes from the service not from the component... that one never happens.. I am not passing the error corectly to my component. Any Idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried removing the whole of catchError in your service? You're currently catching the error there so no error gets to failureCallback on clearCart subscription. If you remove the catchError from service, the exception will be passed to the next catch which is in your clearCart subscription.
If you're feeling confused, you might benefit from reading up on Javascript Promises, just read through the basics so you better understand async, await and .then() and .catch().

Comment: @chuftica You were right once again :) removing the catchError event from service worked! But if I remove the catchError from the servce? how can I trigger the logout on 401 error like in the service?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252084/discussion-between-chuftica-and-weinde).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta rewrite toast present method to accept message as a parameter.

```
async presentToast(message, position: 'bottom') {
const toast = await this.toastController.create({
  message: message,
  duration: 1500,
  position
});
```

And then since you're subscribed to result form http delete request, you can
just put the toast making in clearCart() method something as:

```
this.cartService.clearCart().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.presentToast(data.message);
        this.products = [];
        this.totalProducts = 0;
        this.totalCartPrice = 0;
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this works? One more question tho... how do I show the toast for error? I have updated the code in my question, please take a look

Answer (score 1):

`presentToast()` has not been called anywhere.

Did you check if the data is returning the message to you in your `subscribe` method? If so, we can just pass the `message` in arguments and call `presentToast` in the `subscribe` on `cart.page.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use toastify

https://apvarun.github.io/toastify-js/#

here's a sample snippet:

```
try {
  await login(values.email, values.password);
  navigate('/');
  toast.success('Login Successful!')
} catch (error) {
  toast.error('Invalid User Credentials!')
  setLoading(false);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the idea but I need to use native Ionic components only.